# Why does redirection in crontab result in a zero byte file?

Tags: shell, cron, io-redirection

**System: Xubuntu 13.10**

When I have this crontab entry

```
*/5 * * * * cat /home/dbk/.bash_aliases &> /home/dbk/Desktop/junk
```

`junk` has a byte size of `0`.

Running

```
$ cat /home/dbk/.bash_aliases &> /home/dbk/Desktop/junk
```

gives a file with a proper size and content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probem because `cron` run task with `sh`. `&>` is a shortcut to redirect both `stderr` and `stdout` to the same file in `bash`, not in `sh`.

In `sh`, your command:

```
cat /home/dbk/.bash_aliases &> /home/dbk/Desktop/junk
```

meaning run two commands separately:

- Run `cat /home/dbk/.bash_aliases` in background

  `cat /home/dbk/.bash_aliases &`
- Truncate the junk file.

  `> /home/dbk/Desktop/junk`

So you should use `bash` to run your command in `crontab`:

```
*/5 * * * * bash -c "cat /home/dbk/.bash_aliases &> /home/dbk/Desktop/junk"
```

or using more portable way:

```
*/5 * * * * cat /home/dbk/.bash_aliases > /home/dbk/Desktop/junk 2>&1
```

Comment: Its true that >&1 2>&1 is the analog to &>, but i think that in the portable *`cat`* case it is useless - if *`cat`* errors it should quit and write nothing anyway so >file is enough.

Comment: @mikeserv: Yes, you can see `man bash`, `REDIRECTION` section for more details. No, if cat produce any errors, these errors will be saved to file.

Comment: What kind of errors will be saved to the file?

Comment: @mikeserv: any errors produce by `cat`, i.e you cat a file which doesn't exist.

Comment: Much better than that test -e $file && cat $_ >$tgt

Comment: @mikeserv: not if you actually want to write the error message into the file.